# How to get all td tag value that are inside tr tag in html using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I would like to get all the td values that are inside the tr tag. One of the td is button. So I should get current td values when I am clicking the button. I have tried something like this. But it is not working.

```
<tr class="danger">
<td><input type="text" value="5" id="cash" /></td>
<td><input type="text" value="20" id="turnover"/></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Update" id="update"/></td>
</tr>

$("#update").click(function(){

// Please suggest some logic here
});
```

Can anyone helped me in the Jquery part I would like to get the cash and turnover values when I am clicking update button.

Comment: "But it is not working". What exactly doesn't work? You just have a click handler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can do something like this:

```
$("#update").click(function(){      
   alert(('#cash').val()+' '+$('#turnover').val());
});
```

Comment: this will also get the button

Comment: if you are using `id` (#cash and #turnover) then you don't have to use `.parent` or `.find`. You can directly say `$('#cash').val()`

Comment: The answer which you have updated initially has exactly matches with my requirement. I Ignored last value in my code level. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Kathirvel Appusamy you're welcome :) .. please mark as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [jsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pjdecocq/g84r96sh/2/)
for example i put it in an alert and in the console log window. I don't know if you want to do some math with the values in that case you have to use **parseInt()** function [parseInt explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

```
$("#update").click(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){

      alert($(this).val());
      /* or for example */
      //console.log($(this).val());

    });
});
```